# Magento 2 Data Migration. Redundant tables from M1

Tags: magento2, data-migration

The official docs on migrating data say:

**Remove outdated and redundant data from your Magento 1 database before migration.
Such data may include logs, order quotes, recently viewed or compared products, visitors, event-specific categories, promotional rules, etc.**

Can anyone say which tables hold this information and I can safely empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento maintains several tables for logging. These tables log things such as customer accesses and frequently-compared products.

```
log_customer
log_visitor
log_visitor_info
log_url
log_url_info
log_quote
report_viewed_product_index
report_compared_product_index
report_event
catalog_compare_item
```